# ocaml int and unsigned int

Tags: integer, ocaml

I am trying to find the **last occurrence** of some integer in an array in ocaml:

```
let rec findLastHelper l i loc ret =
  match l with
  | [] -> ret
  | x::xs ->
        match x == i with
        | true -> findLastHelper xs i (loc+1) loc
        | _ -> findLastHelper xs i (loc+1) ret ;;

let findLast l i = (findLastHelper l i 0 -1) ;;
(* let findLast l i = (findLastHelper l i 0 493) ;; *)

let main = Printf.printf "%d\n" (findLast [ 1 ; 6 ; 8 ; 2 ; 9 ; 8 ] 7) ;;
```

If the integer doesn't exist, the code should return `-1`. When I compiled it, I got the following error:

```
$ ocamlopt main.ml -o main
File "main.ml", line 9, characters 20-40:
Error: This expression has type int -> int
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

When I replace the `-1` with some arbitrary **positive value** (493 above), everything goes fine.
What is going on here?

Comment: Note that you're using ````==```` which is the *physical equality* operator. You probably want to use a *structural equality* here, with ````=````. Moreover i would say that pattern matching over a boolean value is bad practice, you can simply use an ````if then else```` here.

Comment: You can merge the two matches like this `| x::xs when x = i -> ... | _::xs -> ...`. Or use `if then else` as suggested.

Comment: Nitpicking: It's bad style to return -1. You should either return an int option or raise the Not_found exception to have cleaner code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml is interpreting `-` as a binary operator in this context. You have to parenthesize `(-1)`.

This is a common OCaml gotcha.

Comment: Alternatively use the unary `~-`:  `findLastHelper l i 0 ~-1`